# Not able to add the correct version of Python in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I have python 3 installed in my machine.

```
C02SD08EG8WL-lm:~ username$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

However Python 3 doesn't show up in the dropdown menu for edit configurations in PyCharm.

[image]

How can I add Python 3 to PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

There is a help [section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-python-sdk.html) about configuring Python SDK in PyCharm. Please check it.